# Counting frequency of keywords with sklearn only yielding zero counts

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp

I am trying to run a Python code that counts the frequency of certain pre-defined keywords in a text. However, I only get zeros when running the script posted below (**i.e. the script does not count any occurence of a keyword in the targeted text**).

**It seems that the error is stuck in the line *"X = vectorizer.fit_transform(text)"* since it always returns an empty variable X.**

What I am trying to get as a result in this short example is a table that lists the counts of each flavour of icecream in a separate column, followed by the sum of individual counts.

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

icecream = ['Vanilla', 'Strawberry', 'Chocolate', 'Peach']
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=icecream, encoding='utf8', lowercase=True, analyzer='word', decode_error='ignore', ngram_range=(1, 1))
dq = pd.DataFrame(columns=icecream)

vendor = 'Franks Store'
text = ['We offer Vanilla with Hazelnut, Vanilla with Coconut, Chocolate and Strawberry']
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(text)
vocab = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
counts = X.sum(axis=0).A1
freq_distribution = Counter(dict(zip(vocab, counts)))
allwords = dict(freq_distribution)
totalnum = sum(allwords.values())
allwords.update({'totalnum': totalnum})

dy = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(allwords, orient='index')
dy.columns = [vendor]
dy = dy.transpose()
dq = dy.append(dq, sort=False)

print(dq)
```

If you have an idea on what might be wrong with this code, I would be very happy if you share it with me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the `lowercase=True` in your parameters, all the found words will be in lowercase. But your vocabulary is this:

```
icecream = ['Vanilla', 'Strawberry', 'Chocolate', 'Peach']
```

The terms here will not match their lowercase counterparts, so everything is 0. You should change them too:

```
icecream = ['vanilla', 'strawberry', 'chocolate', 'peach']
```

The output after that is:

```
                vanilla    strawberry    chocolate    peach    totalnum
Franks Store       2            1            1          0        4.0
```

Now see that `vanilla` has count 2, because it appears two times in the text. If you want to get only the present or absence of a specific flavor, then you can use the `binary=True` param in `CountVectorizer`.

Comment: Thanks @Vivek Kumar, that is exactly the error that stopped my script from working correctly!